# Explicit typing on property of instance

Tags: phpstorm, jetbrains-ide, phpdoc

To help my editor better understand my code, I sometimes need to add a comment like this:

```
/* @var $container Container */
```

This work good, but sometimes I would need something like this:

```
/* @var $this->container Container */
```

Is there something like this?

Comment: 1) What language is that? Is it PHP and you are trying to make typehints using PHPDoc? 2) If this is PHP  -- where are you trying to use such doc comment: inline (in the middle of the method) or at the property declaration? A sample code that would show this moment would be very helpful.

Comment: @LazyOne This is indeed PHP, this comment is in the middle of a function. Here is an example: 
```
$kcmClients = Client::getActiveEventPushClients();
foreach ($kcmClients as $client) {
    /* @var $client Client */
    Client::setActiveClient($client, true);
    $remotePush = RemotePushModel::get();
    if ($remotePush->isRunning()) {
        continue;
    }
    /*other code*/
}```

here is a link to the phpdoc documentation about this https://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLSmartyConverter/HandS/phpDocumentor/tutorial_tags.var.pkg.html

Comment: I've described the correct usage of PHPDoc `@var` tag. In your case (code sample) it's normal to use `@var` IF `Client::getActiveEventPushClients()` is not typehinted properly. Try adding `@return Client[]` for that method -- it will give enough info for PhpStorm to understand that `$kcmClients` is an array of `Client` instances and it will automatically figure out the type for `$client` there in the foreach loop). If you can edit the `Client::getActiveEventPushClients()` code, of course...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things first:

**1.** PHPDoc comments start with `/**`.

For compatibility reasons PhpStorm understands PHPDoc tags in ordinary `/*` comments as well, but you better use the correct symbols for them.

**2.** The correct order of elements for inline `@var` tag can be seen here:
https://github.com/phpDocumentor/fig-standards/blob/master/proposed/phpdoc-tags.md#517-var

```php
/** @var [type] [element_name] [<optional description>] */
```

e.g.

```php
/** @var Container $container */
```

Just as with #1: PhpStorm understands such comments even if elements are swapped around (for compatibility with other (old) IDEs / old code).

---

#### Your actual question:

**Inline `@var` allows typehinting only local / ordinary variables**. You CANNOT use it for compound variables (cannot use `$this->container` or `$someObject->someVar` here).

This is wrong:

```php
/* @var $this->container Container */

// even if it uses correct order/style
/** @var Container $this->container */
```

If anything: such typehints should be provided in the actual class, above the actual property declaration (where you omit the `[element_name]` part) https://github.com/phpDocumentor/fig-standards/blob/master/proposed/phpdoc-tags.md#examples-15

```php
class MyAwesomeClass
{
    /** @var Container Optional description here */
    protected $container;
    ...
}
```